Blazor SectionOutlet and SectionContent within the same page
I want to use both Section-Components within the MainLayout.razor, but it does not work, and I presume, it's not possible. My code so far:
@inject ExampleService ExampleService

<SectionContent SectionName="section-info">
    <span style="color:silver;">@_sectionInfo</span>
</SectionContent>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <div class="top-row px-4" style="justify-content: space-between; z-index: 100;">
                    <div style="justify-content: space-between; color: darkgray;text-align:start;">
                        <SectionOutlet SectionName="section-info" />
                    </div>
...

Assuming user A can change a status on a special page within the blazor app, and the current status of the current user should be shown in the title of the app, in the MainLayout.razor. This is implemented and works like expected, any status change is shown immediately in the title. But other users can change the status for A as well, but how can be the value in the title of A be updated in this case? So I have implemented a Timer in MainLayout, it gets the current status of the current user and could show it in the title ... when it would work. It doesn't. Getting the value works well (same implementation like in the page), I think, the reason is like how the Section works.
The only alternative I could think of is to implement this timer in every page of my app, but ... I hope, there is another, better solution. Any ideas?

I've marked this as a duplicate because it looks like you need to implement a version of the notification pattern.  I've provided the links to two articles on the subject.

It's apparently not that easy to show messages in a parent element sended from a child page in blazor. That's why there are now Sections in Blazor 8. I have a problem with these Sections, and in my opinion doesnt match the recommended threads very well. Sure, I can try an approach without Sections, but ... they are implemented exactly for use cases like mine. I didnt found related information here, so I initiated a new question, and I cannot see, how the both other questions should be duplicates. The same problem, yes, but now we have new tools, and I would like to use one of the new tools.

Create an [MRE] that demonstrates your use case.  There's an awful lot of guesswork for someone trying to answer to take your code and create a MRE to demonstrate how you should do it.

Sorry, I think, I figured out, what exactly the problem is. During my efforts to create a reproducible example I learned, that indeed it is possible to use both Section-Elements within the same page. My problem is the timer resp. working in another than the UI thread. It seems, the Section mechanism works only in main thread.
You're right, I should have done this research first. My apologize.
I think, it's best to delete my question. It's a wrong question. Sorry.

NP.  No apology required.  Sometimes you just need a helping hand in finding the solution yourself as was the case here.  Delete away.
